# Redux dev tool crashing when I use this action

Tags: react-redux, google-chrome-devtools, state, redux-devtools

I'm working on react/redux for some months, and I create this generic method which is a setState like but for redux state. 
It work well, but it when I try to use redux dev tools, it crashed.

Is there some obvious reason for that ? 
I don't have any error message, just : `redux devtool has crashed`

```
case AFFECTVALUE:
            console.log('--> AFFECTVALUE action :', action.name, action.value);
            var newState = { ...state };
            newState[action.name] = action.value
            return {
                ...newState
            }
```

Comment: The only weird thing in the code is that you clone the state twice.

Comment: If the `Redux DevTools` detect a flow of actions that consume too many resources this will crash because can handle all the "side effects" of the reducer. I'll recommend you to check how many changes is your action making, in order to make it shorter.

Comment: @wOxxOm Hi thanks for reply, where did you see I clone it twice ? I clone it just once when I make a copy of the old state and then I return the whole new state.
Which could be probably the error, maybe I should return just the modify key as you said AlbertoPerez . 
thanks for answer me guys
I try and come back

Comment: First clone is `{...state}`, second unnecessary clone is `{...newState}`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should just have return newState;